# How to get webpack4 chunkhash value to use in script src inside the html automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks, splitchunksplugin

How can I get the chunkhash value generated by webpack4 so that I can use it inside my `index.html` to set properly the script src?

Brief context: Hope it not to be a stupid question because I am completely newcomer in webpack, started to learn today. I know how to config, extract js, css, minify them, and maybe all the very basic operations.

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const OptmizerCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: '[chunkhash].bundle.js' // <<<<<<
    },

    mode: 'development',

    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({}),
            new OptmizerCssAssetsPlugin({})
        ],
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            cowsay: 'cowsay-browser'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].css'
        })
    ]
}
```

The relevant part is in `filename: '[chunkhash].bundle.js'` that will produce a filename like `6f9e5dd33686783a5ff8.bundle.js`.

I can use that name in my html like `<script src="dist/6f9e5dd33686783a5ff8.bundle.js"></script>` but *I would have to change it everytime the code was updated/regenerated*.

I was able to use `filename: '[name].bundle.js'` instead of the `chunkhash` but it is not good for caching porpouses.

So, is there any way I can get the `chunkhash` value and use it to set my script src filename in my `index.html` automatically everytime I build the project?

Any valid advice will be wellcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way.

I used the plugin below because it let me use my html as a template file. I just had to remove `link` and `script` tags and let it insert them in final html that it will generate.

This is how I done:

#### 1 - Install html-webpack-plugin

`npm i -D html-webpack-plugin`

#### 2 - Move my `/index.html` as `/src/main.html`

Because my configs will generate a file named `index.html`. Rename template as `main.html` avoids possible confusions

#### 3 - Add it to plugins secion of webpack.config.js

```
// ... other imports here ... //

const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: '[chunkhash].bundle.js' // **** using chunkhash
    },

    mode: 'development',

    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({}),
            new OptmizerCssAssetsPlugin({})
        ],
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all' // **** config the WebPack SplitChunksPlugin
        }
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            cowsay: 'cowsay-browser'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[contenthash].css' // **** using contenthash
        }),

// **** new config: 
        new HtmlPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve('src', 'main.html')
        })
    ]
}
```

#### 4 - That is all!

Now, when I build my project, my `/src/main.html` is parsed, all css `link` tags and script js tags are inserted automatically in a new `/dist/index.html` file (see below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Vacapack</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- LOOK THIS: //-->
    <link href="css/7358f9abc5c8cea68707.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
    <body>
        <pre id="caixa"></pre>
    <!-- AND THESE: //-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="b6183f7997b49195d1f8.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="0e374d6ca9b34e89e18f.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Hope it can help some one else!